# Calling Swift Selector on an Object of Separate Class

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code:

```
struct LoginViewModel {

    var userName :String
    var password :String

    func userNameChanged(textField :UITextField) {

    }
}
```

Inside my view controller I want to attach the editingChanged selector to fire the userNameChanged event:

```
class LoginViewController : UIViewController {

    var loginVM :LoginViewModel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loginVM = LoginViewModel(userName: "", password: "")

        let userNameTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 100, height: 44))
        userNameTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        userNameTextField.addTarget(loginVM, action: #selector("loginVM.userNameChanged"), for: .editingChanged)  // THIS IS NOT WORKING
```

The above line is giving me issues.

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: So why don't you just apply the fixit that it offers? o.0'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A selector either is a string with an Objective C style selector, or a Swift method reference. You need to use one of these two:

Swift style:

```
#selector(LoginViewModel.userNameChanged(textField:))
```

Objective C style:

```
#selector("userNameChangedtextField:")
```

Whenever possible, the Swift style is preferred for its clarity and compiler-enforced correctness.

Comment: Please see the updated question. Still having the same issues. I am running this code in Playground.. maybe thats the issue.

Comment: Oh I just noticed: You can't use structs with the Objective C runtime. You can only use classes which are explicitly annotate `@objc`, or those which descend from an Objective C class, such as `NSObject`.

Comment: Yup! That was it. Thanks a million.